# Reversion of series

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

My question is: Is it intuitive to "assume" that if y can be expressed as an algebraic function of x then the vice-versa must also be true? If so, then how?

[image]

Here's yet another example of the same type and the question remains : "how can we possibly assume that y can be represented in terms of a rational integral function of x just because x can be represented in terms of y?"

[image]

I think I have a conjecture here. I've tried the following in several examples and it seems to work in all of them. Please tell me if it's right.

P(x) and Q(x) are polynomial functions of x

[image]

Comment: If the algebraic function is one to one in some interval (one x corresponds to one y and vice-versa or, as a graph, the plot is strictly increasing or decreasing over the interval) then yes. Otherwise no.

Comment: Well, does this example in the picture make any sense then? Because we don't know about the highest power of x which would determine its one- one nature

Comment: PS: why is that true what you said about one-one  nature making it possible?please elaborate

Comment: The example could make sense in some interval of x values, which would depend on the a, b,  c, ... chosen so that the resulting function is a one to one function, which can happen ($y = x^3$ is one to one for example for any x while $y = x^2$ is one to one for x>0 but not all x). On the PS, draw a graph of an increasing function. Can you see how one x value only has one corresponding y value and vice versa?

Comment: I don't understand why you say that the above method would work iff f(x) is strictly increasing or decreasing function.

Comment: [*Lagrange inversion theorem*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't think that the question fits the tags; can you please fix them?

Answer (score 2):

An infinite polynomial series is typically not an algebraic function.

So long as both series are within their radius of convergence (i.e. if $x$ and $y$ are small enough) and in this case with no leading constant term if $x(0)=y(0)=0$, I do not see why you have a problem.

For example, consider $y=\frac{x}{1-x}$ equivalent to $x=\frac{y}{1+y}$, you will end up with $y=x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ and $x=y-y^2+y^3-\cdots$ at least when both are less than $1$ in absolute terms.

Comment: If y=P(x) where y is a polynomial function of x. Then, if reversion of series is possible, does that necessarily imply that x=Q(y), such that x is an infinite series in y ?

Comment: Example: y=x+x^3. Here x turns out to be equal to : y - y^3 + 3y^5 - 12y^7 +...